# How to create a dynamic API endpoint connection using HTTP or REST connectors in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: rest, azure, api, httpurlconnection, azure-data-factory

I have an external REST based API that I need to create a connection to in order to retrieve data on a regularly scheduled basis (for BI purposes). This API is fairly robust, and supports around 60 distinct endpoints. Also, this same API is used to access information across multiple client sub-domains (e.g. client1.apisource.com, client2.apisource.com, client3.apisource.com, etc.). In other words, the API endpoints are the same for each client subdomain.

So what I'm trying to figure out is whether it's possible to create a single ADF that contains a complete set of pipeline actions for each endpoint **THAT** uses a "dynamic" URL based on the client subdomains? In other words...what I'm trying to see if its possible to create a single ADF that can manage a dynamic list of base URLs.

I tried to parameterize the HTTP and REST connections, but this doesn't appear to Is this possible yet. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-sql-dw/blob/master/ADFv2/ResumeAzureSQLDW.json) of a Web Activity to call a REST API using parameters and expressions. The URL can be an expression like:

```
@concat('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/',pipeline().parameters.SubscriptionID,'/resourceGroups/',pipeline().parameters.ResourceGroup,'/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/',pipeline().parameters.Server,'/databases/',pipeline().parameters.DW,'?api-version=2014-04-01')
```